# WAB Developer Edition Header Controller widgets loading onscreen incorrectly

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, development

Has anyone ever had an issue with Web AppBuilder Developer Edition where the widgets in the header controller  not loading in their proper location?  Sometimes on initial startup of the browser the widgets will load on the map as seen below.

[image: Widgets Loading on map]

Once the browser is resized the widgets return to the HC.  Is there code I could change to ensure these widgets load in the header controller?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in the Foldable and JewelryBox themes in WAB DE 2.7 that was fixed in 2.8. This [thread](https://community.esri.com/thread/208129-web-app-builder-version-27-a-bug-with-2d-jewelry-box-widget-icon-placement) on GeoNet will show a way to resize the window by putting this line in the postCreate function of the HeaderController widget.

```
window._absolutLayoutManager.resize();
```